# Is it possible to connect a FC HBA 8 Gb through 10 Gb Ethernet SFP+?

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, ibm, fibre-channel, hba

I have to connect an IBM Server with a [QLogic EP2532](http://www.qlogic.com/Products/Controllers/Pages/FibreChannelControllers.aspx) to an IBM DS3512 with a [PMC PM8032](http://pmcs.com/products/storage/fibre_channel_controllers/pm8032/). I need two 8 Gb FC LX 1310 nm SFP+ modules and since they seem to be hard to get, I thought would it be possible to take two 10 GbE FC SFP+? I know there's a different encoding, but does FCoE do the job or are there some problems involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the PMC PM8032 is an FC-only controller, it doesn't handle FCoE sorry. FC and FCoE are very different at the L1 and 2 levels.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just found out that I would need a converged network adapter, so even the QLogic EP2532 doesn't seem to support FCoE.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I love a nice detailed storage networking one :)